# Android: How to generate unique random numbers in an array and perform bubble sort?

Tags: android, sorting, random, unique

The following is my code but it doesn't generate unique random numbers

```
Random rand = new Random();

int[] array = new int[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    array[i] = rand.nextInt(n)+1;
}


for (int i = 0; i < ( n - 1 ); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
        if (array[j] > array[j+1]){
            int temp = array[j];
            array[j]   = array[j+1];
            array[j+1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it generate?

Comment: Why are you doing bubble sort?

Comment: n is never initilized

Answer (score 0):

```
public TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    Random r = new Random();

    StringBuffer temp =new StringBuffer("Random numbers:");
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        int i1 = r.nextInt(100 - 0) + 0;

        temp.append(String.valueOf(i1));
        temp.append(String.valueOf(" "));
    }
    tv.setText(temp.toString());
}
//here ,,I generate 10 random numbers and save it in to stringBuffer and dispaly it in to textView..here range is up to 0 to 100...you can take your own Range ...I hope ,,It will help you...
```

Comment: I replaced this line of code  array[i] = rand.nextInt(n)+1; with

Comment: I replaced this line of code array[i] = rand.nextInt(n)+1; with array[i]=rand.nextInt(100 - 0) + 0; but still it generates duplicate numbers

Comment: @ Madhav Gor Do you have any idea on how to shuffle the array elements. Example the array contains number 1 to 100 sequentially and  I shuffle and then perform the sorting operation.

Comment: do you want to stuffle those numbers randomly ??@Sonika

Comment: make one array of 100 and do while loop .in while loop check generated number is available in array or not..if is not available than add that number otherwise generate another random number..@Sonika

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Since generated unique random numbers didn't work. I thought of shuffling the numbers after generating the numbers sequentially and then performing a sort operation. Will work out with your suggestion. @Madhav Gor

Answer (score 0):

check this out!... it works for me

```
Random rand = new Random();

int n = 10;
int[] array = new int[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    array[i] = (int) (rand.nextDouble() * n + 1);
}


for (int i = 0; i < ( n - 1 ); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
        if (array[j] > array[j+1]){
            int temp = array[j];
            array[j]   = array[j+1];
            array[j+1] = temp;
        }
    }
}

for (int piece: array) {
  System.out.println(piece);
}
```

Comment: It didn't work out when I display the sorted array its generated duplicate numbers. The following code I had used to display the array in text view.

Comment: for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                {
                    res+=String.valueOf(array[i])+"\n";
                }
                txtResult.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
                txtResult.setText(res);
            } ;